# monit: The control file '/etc/monit/monitrc' must be owned by you

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ubuntu, monit

I've the following details to access in monitrc:

```
set httpd port 2812 and
    use address localhost  # only accept connection from localhost
    allow 0.0.0.0/0.0.0.0
#    allow admin:monit      # require user 'admin' with password 'monit'

   allow @mygroup
```

Answer (score 1):

Somewhere inside the Monit's source file `p.y` there is code which checks `monitrc` with a comment saying:

```
/*
 * Secure check the monitrc file. The run control file must have the
 * same uid as the REAL uid of this process, it must have permissions
 * no greater than 700 and it must not be a symbolic link.
 */
```

The message `The control file '/etc/monit/monitrc' must be owned by you` is generated by this check. To fix it you need to change either the `monitrc` file owner or the user which runs Monit daemon, so that they are the same.

This also follows from the [Monit documentation](https://mmonit.com/monit/documentation/monit.html#THE-MONIT-CONTROL-FILE):

> To protect the security of your control file and passwords the control
>   file must have read-write permissions no more than 0700 (u=xrw,g=,o=);
>   Monit will complain and exit otherwise.